# How to preserve the message sent order at TCP server side with multiple clients

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, f#

I have two PCs connected by direct Ethernet cable over 1Gbps link. One of them act as TCP Server and other act as TCP Client/s. Now I would like to achieve maximum possible network throughput between these two.

Options I tried:
Creating multiple clients on PC-1 with different port numbers, connecting to the TCP Server. The reason for creating multiple clients is to increase the network throughput but here I have an issue.

[image: setup]

I have a buffer Queue of Events to be sent to Server. There will be multiple messages with same Event Number. The server has to acquire all the messages then sort the messages based on the Event number. Each client now dequeues the message from Concurrent Queue and sends to the server. After sent, again the client repeats the same. I have put constraint on the client side that Event-2 will not be sent until all messaged labelled with Event-1 is sent. Hence, I see the sent Event order correct. And the TCP server continuously receives from all the clients.

Now lets come to the problem:
The server is receiving the data in little random manner, like I have shown in the image. The randomness between two successive events is getting worse after some time of acquisition. I can think of this random behaviour is due to parallel worker threads being executed for IO Completion call backs.

technology used: F# Socket Async with SocketEventArgs

Solution I tried: Instead of allowing receive from all the clients at server side, I tried to poll for the next available client with pending data then it ensured the correct order but its performance is not at all comparable to the earlier approach.

[image]

I want to receive in the same order/ nearly same order (but not non-deterministic randomness) as being sent from the clients. Is there any way I can preserve the order and also maintain the better throughput? What are the best ways to achieve nearly 100% network throughput over two PCs?

Comment: TCP is a network protocol layered on top of IP. The purpose of TCP is to guarantee, that a sent package is received. If a packet is lost (that happens even under best conditions) it is resent. That means, you can't guarantee that the order of sent packages is preserved. You would need another protocol on top of TCP (That will lower your throughput).

Comment: It seems that splitting your client into three processes is causing most of your problems;  I don't understand how that is supposed to help.  Surely one process can send just as much data as three processes?  You will then have much less of an issue with sequencing.  Maybe some sort of streaming protocol would be more useful in this situation?

Comment: If you want to preserve the order you will have to take care of the ordering yourself. The easiest way I can think of off the top of my head is to add a number to each message and then sort them once they are received.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé TCP already guarantees order over a single connection.  It seems that the problem here is the fact that multiple TCP connections are being used.

Comment: I agree with the other comments asking why you think this design would in any way improve throughput in the first place. If you are dealing with a single network connection, adding clients just adds contention and is likely to make it _slower_, not faster. If you had multiple network connections, you could use a "multi-path" implementation but, yes...that's going to be quite a bit more complicated, with the need for the client to demux the data into the multiple paths, and then the server to reintegrate the data on receipt. The data will need to include sequence #'s to do this.

Comment: (And no, the comment from @Romano doesn't seem useful...on a single TCP connection, ordering _is_ guaranteed. This isn't about TCP; it's about splitting the data between multiple connections, thus preventing TCP from knowing what the order should be.)

Comment: "What are the best ways to achieve nearly 100% network throughput over two PCs?" Write software dedicated to this purpose. CPUs and memory are faster than network connections. If your application isn't saturating the line, then that's a problem of your application, and if you need in-order delivery of data, the most appropriate solution is not to run multiple instances of it -- that just creates more problems. Fix the root cause, which is your ineffective TCP code. Use asynchronous I/O, buffering, threading. Don't go multi-process.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I suspect "clients" in this case are TCP-clients within one application, and not multiple applications. Alternatively: It looks like Mahesh believes one connection isn't sufficient to saturate the line.

Comment: @Bent Tranberg, yes you are exactly right, I have one application with multiple TCP clients connecting to the server. The reason for creation of multiple clients is to saturate the line and I can see throughput is increased but I am facing problems with order.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, Yes I have Sequence nos (Event Nos) assigned to the data

Comment: _"I have Sequence nos (Event Nos) assigned to the data"_ -- yes, but do you have the multiple network adapters at both ends to take advantage of that? Because if you don't, all you're doing is complicating your life and creating contention. As has @Jeroen and others have pointed out, your computer is way faster than the network. If you can't keep the network pipe filled, it's because of inefficiencies in your program. The way to deal with that isn't to make your program more complicated. It's to make it _less_ complicated, and _more_ efficient.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, I have seen better throughput with multiple TCP streams sending the data than a single TCP stream. The reason could be more receive buffers on Server side if multiple TCP clients are accepted and hence it can accommodate more data on receiver side keeping the line busy. Now, the problem is I need to synchronize the data on receiver side without hurting the performance.

Comment: _"I have seen better throughput with multiple TCP streams sending the data than a single TCP stream"_ -- only in programs where the per-client implementation is poor. _"The reason could be more receive buffers on Server side if multiple TCP clients are accepted"_ -- a single-connection implementation can use multiple buffers, to ensure the network pipeline remains filled at all time. None of this suggests it's useful or desirable to split a single client into multiple connections.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments, a single TCP connection is likely to give you the highest throughput, if it's TCP you want to use.

You can possibly achieve slightly (really marginally) higher throughput with UDP, but then you have the hassle of recreating all the goodies TCP gives you for free.

If you want bidirectional high volume high speed throughput (as opposed to high volume just one way at a time), then it's possible one connection for each direction is easier to cope with, but I don't have that much experience with it.

Design tips

You should keep the connection open. The client will need to ask "are you still there?" at regular intervals if no other communication goes on. (On second thought, I realize that the only purpose of this is to allow quick reponse and the possiblity for the server to initiate a message transaction. So I revise it to: keep the connection open for a full transaction at least.)

Also, you should split up large messages - messages over a certain size. Keep the number of bytes you send in each chunk to a maximum round hex number, typically 8K, 16K, 32K or 64K on a local network. Experiment with sizes. The suggested max sizes has been optimal since Windows 3 at least. You need some sort of protocol with a chunck consisting of a fixed header (typically a magic number for check and resynch, a chunk number also for check and for analysis, and a total packet length) followed by the data.

You can possibly further improve throughput with compression (usually low quick compression) - it depends very much on the data, and whether you're on a fast or slow network.

Then there's this hassle that one typically runs into - problems with the Nagle algorith - and I no longer remember enough of the details there. I believe I used to overcome that by sending an acknowledgement in return for each chunk sent, and I suspect by doing that you satisfy the design requirements, and so avoid waiting for the last bytes to come in. But do google this.

Comment: Nagle's algorithm doesn't matter for total throughput, only for latency. It limits how often "partially full buffers" are sent - a full buffer is always sent right away.

Comment: Yes, but if you design your stuff in the wrong way, you risk waiting a very long time, or in theory even indefinitely, for the last few bytes to come in. I know, because I've bumped into this problem countless times in the past.

Comment: @Bent Tranberg, I have seen better throughput with multiple TCP streams sending the data than a single TCP stream. The reason could be more receive buffers on Server side if multiple TCP clients are accepted and hence it can accommodate more data on receiver side keeping the line busy. Now, the problem is I need to synchronize the data on receiver side without hurting the performance.

Comment: _"you risk waiting a very long time, or in theory even indefinitely, for the last few bytes to come in"_ -- no, you don't. Nagle's algorithm waits hundreds of ms at most. It doesn't wait indefinitely. And disabling it can lead to data being sent with incomplete buffers, which increases network overhead and reduces throughput.

Comment: _"You can possibly achieve slightly (really marginally) higher throughput with UDP"_ -- this would be true only in scenarios where loss of data is acceptable. And there are lots of scenarios like that. But that's not the case here, and TCP is both designed and implemented to optimize throughput for streaming.

Comment: _"you should split up large messages - messages over a certain size"_ -- TCP doesn't have any concept of "messages", so it makes no sense to suggest limiting the size of messages. Whatever size buffers you use in the program, the network layer is going to chop up the data into ~1500 byte chunks for transmission over the network (or larger in some cases, depending on configuration of the hardware).

Comment: _"You need some sort of protocol with a chunck consisting of a fixed header"_ -- not with TCP you don't. TCP guarantees ordering. It doesn't matter _at all_ how you chunk the data, at the other end it's just a stream. You could use 1 byte buffers and the remote endpoint could use 10K buffers, or vice a versa. Each endpoint deals with the stream at the buffer size appropriate for that endpoint.

Comment: I am thinking of data that you send on top of TCP as a message, e.g. a message containing a large file. One can either connect/send/close on TCP, or one can keep the connection open for what I am used to call a single transaction, or one can keep it open continuously. If you just open/send/close, then there's no need for a protocol on top of TCP, but it's slower for certain scenarios, and the server can't initiate communication.

Comment: For very large data, I have found splitting it into chunks of a certain size gives me best performance. Sending a one gig file in one go doesn't seem like a good idea. Of course this has nothing at all to do with the low level stuff, but with how the application and framework behaves.

Comment: I have never observed UDP loss in a local network, or locally in a machine for that matter. Not saying it can't happen of course, but you can build systems with local UDP communication on the assumption retransmits won't slow your system down. I once used it to build inter process communication for a distributed server, on win32, not .net.

Comment: "Sending a one gig file in one go doesn't seem like a good idea." That specific scenario is covered by `TransmitFile` (just saying). And if you want to see UDP loss in a local network, try sending lots of data from lots of different clients. Yes, I've managed to cause UDP loss in a perfectly reliable LAN. If you overwhelm the stack, packets will get dropped silently rather than being buffered (by design, of course). This was for a logging solution where packet loss wasn't critical.